# Pass explicit char array in function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char, explicit

I have a char array

`char theArray[] = { 0xAA, 0x01, 0x27, 0x08 };`

and I'm normally passing the array like

`myFunction(theArray)`

But I have several other explicit array initializations. When I try to do a

`myFunction({ 0xAA, 0x01, 0x27, 0x08 })`,

the compiler says:

> Error: excess elements in scalar initializer

How can I pass my explicit array directly?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use a `std::array<unsigned char,4>` instead of a `char[]` array:

```
#include <array>

void myFunction(const std::array<unsigned char,4>& theArray) {
}

int main() {
     myFunction({{ 0xAA, 0x01, 0x27, 0x08 }});
     myFunction({{ 0xAA, 0x01, 0x27, 0x08 }});
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8ac375a2f1bf05d)

---

#### Why `unsigned char`?

The value `0xAA` doesn't fit for a `signed char`, there will be a compiler error.

#### Why `const`?

Because you'll get an rvalue from the initializer list, this can be passed as `const` reference only, or being copied to a by value parameter.

Comment: Ok thank you. But can you explain why in this case the consequent c++ function / argument mechanism is brocken?

Comment: @Christoph, nothing is broken. You might want to read on arrays decaying to understand better.

Comment: Wouldn't `std::initializer_list` work better here? I never used it, I might be wrong.

Comment: @leemes It's used implicitly anyways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, `array` uses it in its constructor. But isn't a direct usage of `initializer_list` more "lightweight"? I mean, why using `array` at all?

Comment: @leemes Probably depends on what you want to do with `theArray`. For some operations `std::array`'s interface may be more convenient.

Comment: Without knowing what the function does with it's data, we would not know what's better - array, initializer list or a template parameter pack. So it's better to stick to original design as close as possible.

Comment: @SergeyA Which _original design_ actually? Passing a pointer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, no, pass an array - as OP attempted. (As opposed to pass an initializer list or template paramter pack). Hint - I am siding with you here! :)

Comment: @SergeyA [It doesn't work well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64c121e4fab7723d), otherwise I would have changed my answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, i think, there is a misuderstanding. What I am trying to say is that OP was trying to pass a built-in static array. This doesn't work (we know why). You provided a most close alternative - pass an `std::array`, which is a very close to what OP was doing. This is a very good answer which I upvoted. There are also other ways to pass a sequence of unsigned chars to a function - for example, through initializer lists or template parameter packs. But those (in answer) would be inferior to yours, because they deviate from original OP's intent. Makes more sense?

Comment: What if we use `myFunction(std::unique_ptr<char[]>{new char[4]{0xAA,0x01,0x27,0x08}}.get());`? This answers the question and doesn't change the function being called.

Answer (score -4):

The answer depends on what you mean by "pass my explicit array directly".

When you say that you have a char array:

```
char theArray[] = { 0xAA, 0x01, 0x27, 0x08 };
```

You are declaring the array on the stack. When it goes out of scope the memory is released.

From within the function there is no way to tell how the memory was allocated. So even without knowing more about he function we can infer that if you were passing `char theArray[] = { 0xAA, 0x01, 0x27, 0x08 };` and the function wasn't releasing memory then we could never expect it to do so with another call that still passes a pointer.

The memory must be allocated to something and the syntax `myFunction(new char[]{0xAA,0x01,0x27,0x08 });` would not be allowed.

But if we use a smart pointer we can do it one line:

```
myFunction(std::unique_ptr<char[]>{new char[4]{0xAA,0x01,0x27,0x08}}.get());
```

Comment: You should check first.  This will not compile.

Comment: Point taken. It didn't compile as originally written. I've combined the idea from Chexxor. :)

Comment: To whomever voted this down after the update: Please explain how a correct answer is not acceptable? OP didn't ask for a general treatise on program design. Only how to pass the values in this example.

Comment: You are not passing an array. You pass a pointer to one, which will eventually leak unless deleted somewhere. So OP needs to change two things about his function, which you don't mention. Thus I treat it as being not a valid answer.

Comment: @leemes Clearly OP's function has been taking a pointer. The decay was being used. You don't know what the function does, so this answers the question as written. You are trying to fix OP's program and perhaps his libraries in general.

Comment: No, original OP's code was an attempt to use automaically managed static array. You replaced it with a dynamic array which needs to be managed - so you **must** provide the code for this.

Comment: @flatmouse What OP's function exactly is taking wasn't mentioned. It could be a reference to an array, or a pointer (to which the array is decayed). You guess the latter, while the first would be better. When really passing a pointer (like in your code), you are clearly not passing an array at all, even if OP (maybe accidentally?) also did that due to the array being decayed. However, that's only one problem. The other is the memory leak, which is much worse.

Comment: If he is passing the array by reference then this will not work.  Even if he is accepting a pointer you now need to delete that pointer in the function which is not good as you cannot tell if the pointer was allocated with new or not inside the function.  So how do you know when to call delete to prevent the memory leak?  If you don't then you have a memory leak and an and in IMHO an answer that gives the OP a memory leak is a bad answer.

Comment: You still fail to address how to release the memory.  How do you differentiate between what was passed was an static array or it was a dynamically allocated array?